# Not able to read the plist data using siri

Tags: ios, swift, siri

I am using one Siri app. And I am saving data in `plist` and retrieve the contacts. But not able to get the `plist` date. Here is the code :

here I am getting the saved data and the path is :

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EB3CE9B8-EECC-459E-9AF0-749E10C26F95/Documents/data.plist
```

But same when i use siri and in my code when i try to get the plist data its printing empty value:

```
i tried nsuserdefault also.And the path is :

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/80E47164-FC1F-4DBA-AAD5-D0F37107BD42/Documents/data.plist
```

Not sure where I am getting issues. But when I try to get data in my app delegate from my plist data. I am getting. But why not using Siri I am not getting contacts data. And also even `NSUserDefault` also not working.

Note: when I use Siri, my app will be in the background, or terminate or might be active.

Thanks in advance!

Update :

I tried like :

**to save data**

```
let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.example.app")
        defaults?.set(23, forKey: "siridata")
```

**to read:**

```
let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.example.app")
        let returnValue = defaults?.double(forKey: "siridata")
```

It's not printing the `23`.Its printing `0.0`

In my target :

```
My app name group : group.com.example.app
My PaymentIntentExtension : group.com.example.app
```

I am getting this in consle :

> [User Defaults] Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x101531c40> (Domain: group.com.example.app, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers, detaching from cfprefsd

Answer (score 0):

The Intents extension and main app are in separate sandboxes, so you need to use a shared container via an "App Group".

Here's an article on how to do it: https://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions

Once you've setup the App Group in both the main app target and the extension target's capabilities, you can get the location to save the file using `containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1412643-containerurl

Sharing UserDefaults works similarly, also using App Groups and `init(suiteName:)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1409957-init